# DependencyProperty and UserControl in WPF

Tags: wpf, user-controls, customproperty

I created a UserControl with a Label and a Rectangle inside 2 grid rows.
I added the property

```
public string SetText
{
    get
    {
        return (string)GetValue(mLabel.ContentProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(mLabel.ContentProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Usage of the property

```
<local:PlayerMiniImage SetText="Player 1" ...
```

When I used the property, the font of the label changed and the rectangle disappeared
Have any idea?

Comment: How is SetText bound in PlayerMiniImage ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define a UserControl...

```
<UserControl x:Class="...">
    <Border>
        <!-- ... -->
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

Then everything inside it, here a `Border`, is the `Content`, hence if you set the `ContentProperty` everything will be replaced.

---

To set the label content create a new DP:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelContentProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("LabelContent", typeof(object), typeof(MyUserControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
public object LabelContent
{
    get { return (object)GetValue(LabelContentProperty); }
    set { SetValue(LabelContentProperty, value); }
}
```

and bind the label to it:

```
<Label Content="{Binding LabelContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```